# Google Search Results Issue

Tags: iis, google-index

Recently all our websites URL's have appeared as https:// in google's search results.  However, that url is not even valid for our website as it should be http:// for all of them.  We're not sure what caused google to think https:// is correct.  If you click any of these links none of them will work correctly.

So if you search for our website in google the results come back as this:

```
https://ourdomain.com
https://ourdomain.com/site2
```

When in reality it should be:

```
http://ourdomain.com
http://ourdomain.com/site2
```

Is this a certificate error or something in IIS that is causing issues?  We do use a certificate on one specific website but on none of the others.